# Is there a way to calculate the average duration between multiple dates in SQL/excel?

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, excel-formula, google-bigquery

I have run a query to look for the dates of purchases made. In some cases I get multiple dates for a single customer.
I would like to calculate the average duration between each purchase made for each customer. How do I do that?

Sample:

```
|    Date   | Customer Name |
|-----------|---------------|
| Jun 16,20 | Customer 1    |
| Jul 7, 20 | Customer 1    |
| Dec 6, 21 | Customer 1    |
| Dec 26, 21| Customer 1    |
| Jan 5, 22 | Customer 1    |
```

Any ideas?
I'm okay to do this in either excel or sql...

Comment: `Average duration = ( MAX(Date) - MIN(Date) ) / ( COUNT(Date) - 1 )`

Answer (score 1):

See few options below (BigQuery)

```
select customer_name, 
  extract(day from max(date) - min(date)) / (count(*) - 1),
  (unix_date(max(date)) - unix_date(min(date))) / (count(*) - 1)
from your_table
group by customer_name
```